# I'm new to programming and I'm not able to understand this code

Tags: java, if-statement

```
class IfSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y;
        x = 10;
        y = 20;
        if (x < y) System.out.println("x is less than y");
        x = x * 2;
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");
        x = x * 2;
        if (x > y) System.out.println("x is greater than y");
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");
    }
}
```

Output according to me should be

> x is less than y
>   x is equal to y
>   x is equal to y

But the actual output is

> x is less than y
>   x is equal to y
>   x is greater than y

Please explain me how is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

`x = x * 2;` actually assigns the result of `x * 2` *to* `x`.

You are applying that twice. So `x` is successively 10, 20, then 40.

It doesn't somehow *reset* to 10.

As you progress, you might find the equivalent statement `x *= 2;` clearer. I do.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to explain the code below, check my comments

```
class IfSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y;//You created two variables
        x = 10;// 10 was assigned to variable x
        y = 20;// while 20 was assigned to variable y

        //you checked if x is less then y which is true cause 10 is less than 20
        if (x < y) System.out.println("x is less than y");

        x = x * 2;//You mutiplied x (which is 10) times 2 making x = 20

        //You checked if x is equal to y which is true cause x is now 20
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");

        x = x * 2;//You multiplied x (which is 20) by 2 given a new value of 40

        //You checked if 40 (x new value) is greater than y(value is 20) which is true
        if (x > y) System.out.println("x is greater than y");

        //This will be false cause 40 (x value) is not equal to 20 (y value) 
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");
    }
}
```

For the expected Output you need to do this:

```
class IfSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y;
        x = 10;
        y = 20;
        if (x < y) System.out.println("x is less than y");
        x = x * 2;
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");
        x = x * 2;
        y = y * 2;//Now y will be 40 (i.e 20 *2)
        if (x > y) System.out.println("x is greater than y");
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before `if (x > y) System.out.println("x is greater than y");`

x is multiplied by 2 for the **second** time.

Therefore 20*2 = 40... which is greater than y=20.

To note: During the first multiplication 10*2, the resulting value 20 was stored into the variable x (a location in memory).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple,everytime you are checking the condition,you are assigning a new value for 'x' by multiplying it by two. Compiler interprets line by line and set the value,which was assigned at the last.

Answer (score 0):

when x= 10

```
x=x*2
now x=20
and then again
x=x*2
now x=40
```

so first it prints x is less than 
than x=y
and then x is greater than y

simply maths its not programming

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of x=10 and y=20.
After execution of if `(x < y)`
X is multiplied by 2 i,e 10*2 so now x=20
After execution of if `(x == y)`
X is again multiplied by 2 i,e 20*2 so now x=40
So the if condition `(x>y)` i.e, 40>20  which is true hence its giving that out out which is expected.

Comment: Hint: your question is badly formatted (why are you using "code" indentation here?!) And it is also very hard to figure how your explanations relate to the original code.